# Java mouse cursor image not showing up, repaint error

Tags: java, repaint

I create two cursors for my video game:

```
        // blank cursor image
        BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        blankCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(
                cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");

        customCursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(
            MY_IMAGE, new Point(0,0) , "custom cursor");
```

I am setting my mouse cursor to blank when I launch my game:

```
this.setCursor(blankCursor);
```

Then later, under certain conditions I want to show my cursor again:

```
this.setCursor(customCursor);
```

The blank cursor works. The custom cursor doesn't show up ever. (note that I know the line is running because I am using `System.out.println`. I also know that the cursor icon works because if I switch the two around then the `customCursor` shows and the blank cursor does not)

So the question is: what repainting/refreshing/revalidating do I need to do in order to show my second cursor icon?

Also I am pretty sure there is no `setVisible()` method for cursors but if there is a different better solution that would be welcome as well.

Comment: What are your cursor format? png, ico? And the system? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Haha actually you have solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure repaint or validate will help in your case: the cursor is probably paint by the system and has certain restriction. In your case, the image is probably invalid and made transparent, which is what [createCustomCursor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createCustomCursor(java.awt.Image,%20java.awt.Point,%20java.lang.String)) does:

> Creates a new custom cursor object. If the image to display is
>   **invalid, the cursor will be hidden (made completely transparent)**, and
>   the hotspot will be set to (0, 0).

Comment: @FatFrank until you actually see the cursor in your running program, it would be wisest not to make such assumptions. For best help here, consider creating and posting a valid [mre], one that uses online images for the cursor images.

Comment: Thanks Hovercraft Full of Eels very helpful! The minimal reproducible example worked fine demonstrating to me my error!

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels: I had a module which was running in the background managing key-listeners, that was interfering with my set cursor change action (because the cursor was being changed on a pause event).